# How to change few slides by mouse scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have standard swiper with slidesperview:3

```
var videoSwiper = new Swiper('.video-swiper', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  mousewheel: true,
});
```

When I scroll a mouse it goes one more slides forward, but I need the next three slides forward.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your HTML looks like, but [here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-1-default-smbnbj?file=index.html) an working example